# Someone know to do permanent enviroment variables with .env file?

Tags: environment-variables

My Problem is, I want to do permanent enviroment variables, but I don't want modify .bashrc or .profile to add export varible=content. Because that I see that is possible with .env file but i do and don't work

Comment: You *have* to set it in `.bashrc` or some other file that's executed on startup of the shell. There's no other feasible way. You *can* `source .env` of course, but ...

Comment: Any reason why you will not modify `.bashrc`? That's a pretty imposing restriction to set on yourself when using Linux.

Comment: You could use `/etc/environment`.

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"i do and don't work"*? What did you try, exactly, and what happened?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** I'm not sure how this relates to the Ubuntu OS. You might be better served asking this question over on the [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).